# DMARC fails using custom domain with Sendy, messages marked as spam

Tags: email, dns, newsletter, dmarc, sendy

I use Sendy in a custom domain. So far, so good: validated the custom domain via email in Sendy and I can send messages.

But it fails to pass DMARC, which triggers [this horrendous message](https://proton.me/support/email-has-failed-its-domains-authentication-requirements-warning) in Proton, Gmail, plus send messages to spam folder.

Here's a mail-tester: https://www.mail-tester.com/test-pkc3siz78&reloaded=1

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I just had this exact same problem this week using Sendy.
To solve the problem, make sure to have all of these configured correctly:

DKIM: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/send-email-authentication-dkim-easy.html

SPF: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/send-email-authentication-spf.html

DMARC: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/send-email-authentication-dmarc.html

MAIL FROM: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/mail-from.html

And the final step to make it work is to make sure that you have the DKIM signatures: Enabled for the verified email identity.

The Identities are found in: SES -> Configuration -> Verified Identities
Then to enable the DKIM signatures navigate to the auth tab and click on edit:

[DKIM verification status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hihv.png)